# how to use my own custom classes with entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

i am very much new to Entity Framework and i just used this in nop commerce 1.9 so i dont know how to implement Entity Framework from scratch for a new project. i created the database with all table and make complete relationship in all table. and also created the project for my class an example of a class is

```
 class BE_Room
    {
        #region properties
        public int RoomId { get; set; } 
        public string RoomType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } 
        public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; } 
        public bool IsSmoking { get; set; } 
        public int Status { get; set; } 
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; } 
        public int CreatedBy { get; set; } 
        public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

and the table schema for this class in db is as following

```
RoomId  int
RoomType    nvarchar
Description nvarchar
NumberOfRooms   int
IsSmoking   bit
Status  tinyint
CreatedDate smalldatetime
UpdatedDate smalldatetime
CreatedBy   int
UpdatedBy   int
Rank    int
```

now when i add the edmx file it will genrate all the classes for all entities and make a single file for all classes.

but as i am following nop commerce  1.9 there is a single .edmx file for all entities but they have separeted classes for products, discounts.

how it can be achived ?

as i am new to entity framework  so my question might be not clear , so please comment if you want to know anything else or i am missing in my question.

**EDITED**

as  i am searching continuously on Google i found that what i want to achieve can be done with POCO entity generator

so my question is now what steps should i follow for POCO Entity Genrator to create a single .`edmx` file but separate entities classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through this [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx).